# Why do I have the error `injection "store" not found` when I try `this.store.commit()`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to store values using VueX. I'm using Vuex 4.0 not the 3.0.

So I'm trying to commit a value like this, as I was used to in Vuex 3 :

```
...
 this.$store.commit("changerusername", u)
...
```

So I tried this :

Inside my `main.js` I have this :

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { store } from "./store";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(store);
app.mount("#app");
```

Inside my `store/store.js`, I have this :

```
import vue from "vue";
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export const store = createStore({
  state: {
    username: null,
    token: null,
  },
  getters: {
    getUsername: function (state) {
      return `${state.username}`;
    },
  },
  mutation: {
    changeusername: function (state, newusername) {
      state.username = newusername;
    }
  },
});
```

`App.vue` have this :

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "app",
});
</script>
```

Ok now, inside the file where I want to do my commit, I wrote this :

Imports :

```
import { useQuasar } from "quasar";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
```

The setup :

```
    setup() {
      const store = useStore();

      return {
        store,
      };
    },
```

And I use it like this :

```
      loginArrow: function (u, p) {
        this.store.commit("changeusername", u);
      },
```

But when I do this I got this error : `injection "store" not found.`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The question doesn't specifically say you use Quasar, but it's important. You could just import `store` object in generic Vue app, but global store should be treated differently in an app with SSR

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Composition API you could change your `loginArrow` function to something like this because the keyword `this` does not work in the Composition API:

```js
const loginArrow = (u, p) => {
    store.commit("changeusername", u);
}
```

You can also try to use `store.value.commit(...)` instead of `store.commit(...)`

Comment: Is it possible to use it without Composition API ? If yes, can you give me an example please

Comment: Have you tried this:

```js
loginArrow: function (u, p) {
    store.commit("changeusername", u);
},
```
Basically same as before, but without the ```this``` keyword.

If that doesn't work, can you post the entire code/component where you want to use the loginArrow function?

Comment: @icapinto90 But you already use composition api in the question

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why that wasn't working. it wasn't in the function but in quasar directly.

In the folder app/.quasar there's 4 files app.js, client-entry.js, client-prefetch.js and quasar-user-options.js.

Normally it configure automatically but idk why quasar didn't so I did it manually by comparing with another project.

Thank you for the help !